# Safe to hide a private RSA key behind #if debug?

Tags: c#, cryptography

First question here after having found so many answers already....

I made a license class, which is signed using RSA. Checking the signature is done using the public key, creating the signature using the private key. As I create licenses only myself the signing/creation code needs not to be in the license class itself (released code). But on the other hand I'd like to have all class-code together and not write the license signing/creation code in a partial class that is even part of another project (local license manager application). Is it safe to do something like the following:

```
public class License {
    private const string publicRSA = "whatever";

    #if DEBUG

    public void CreateLicense()
    {
        string privateRSA = "whatever again";

        // Do license creation stuff below...

    }

    #endif

    // Other license code follows below....

}
```

The clue is that in the release version the private key should not be visible, and also not the code that creates the license, but for me there is no problem to locally run a license manager application that uses this class in debug mode when I need to generate a license now and then...

Am I missing something here (with respect to precompiler behavior in C#...)? Apart from releasing a debug version by accident, can I shoot myself in the foot by doing this? Are there better options?

Comment: The compiled release version will not have the code that's inside the `#if DEBUG` directive, so I think it should be safe for development. However, once you start releasing the software, I would remove it all together just so you would not accidentally send a debug version to a client.

Comment: @Zohar. After the application is released, I still use the same class in a local license manager to generate licenses for people who use the released code. So I cannot remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `if` directive does not compile the code within it if the condition is not met, which means that a released code cannot be disassembled to get the private RSA key.

> When the C# compiler encounters an #if directive, followed eventually by an #endif directive, it will compile the code between the directives only if the specified symbol is defined.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

However, we don't know what kind of optimization the compiler or Visual Studio might use while building, and so it might compile the RSA code in some other temporary files for caching or whatever, even though the released code does not contain the code specified.

Moreover, it is advised to store such critical information in another file in another folder, outside the source control, so that it is not committed mistakenly, and have a configuration key to store the path of the file, so it is accessed by runtime. You can find more in this page:

https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/best-practices-for-deploying-passwords-and-other-sensitive-data-to-aspnet-and-azure

Comment: Good information, thanks. I changed my setup such that CreateLicense() is still between #if DEBUG / #endif, but the private RSA key is read from a file which is not in the project tree that will be released.